# Can I use JDK from PhpStorm to Android SDK manager?

Tags: java, android, sdk, phpstorm, android-sdk-manager

I want to run sdkmanager from command line but it required install JDK, but I am afraid my storage can not handle it (full). As far as I know PhpStorm from IntelliJ required JDK (maybe have built in), so can I use PhpStorm's JDK to Android SDK manager?

I only install [commandline SDK manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) without Android Studio.